# Не отсылается сообщение по udp

Tags: c++, udp, unreal-engine-4

Есть код:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void OnBoneHit(FString bone);

void ACameraPawn::OnBoneHit(FString bone)
{
    ARamaUDPSender sender;
    sender.StartUDPSender("UdpSendSocket", "127.0.0.1", 11111);
    sender.RamaUDPSender_SendString(bone);
}
```

Вызывается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ловлю сообщения по заданному порту, ничего не приходит. Код udp взят [здесь](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/index.php?title=UDP_Socket_Sender_Receiver_From_One_UE4_Instance_To_Another).

Comment: логи пишутся, что сокет инициализирован успешно (из примера)? чем проверяете приём?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, код Rama взят почти без изменений, у него логи не пишутся,  сделано так:

Comment: if (!SenderSocket)
 {
  ScreenMsg("No sender socket");
  return false;
 }

Comment: Для проверки приёма написал обычную программу на C#, давно написал, прекрасно работает.

Comment: в коде рама есть строки: `UE_LOG(LogTemp,Log,TEXT("Rama ****UDP**** Sender Initialized Successfully!!!"));` и `ScreenMsg("UDP~ Send Succcess! Bytes Sent = ",BytesSent );` Для отладки лучше вернуть их обратно. Для проверки лучше использовать не самописные штуки, а что-то надежное и проверенное, например геркулес. Кроме того проблема может быть и в файрволе винды, если не выставлены разрешения

Comment: @goldstar_labs, а то, что при событии я в студию не попадаю, хотя в указанном методе поставлена точка прерывания -- это нормально? Что, отлаживать, как обычно под студией, нельзя? Про файевол спасибо, очень похоже, я как то нечаянно в самом начале кликнул на его сообщении при загрузке анриал, а потом вспомнил, что там галочка на домашнюю сеть не стояла, только на публичные, да подумал, ещё раз предупредит, но нет, я и забыл. Попробую повозиться. А этот ScreenMsg куда выводит сообщения? И этот лог, я его не удалял? Меньше недели с анриалом работаю, совсем новичок, простите за глупые вопросы.

Comment: 1) не нормально, если брейкпоинт стоит, то должно туда попадать 2) отлаживать можно и нужно 3) добавьте в исключения файрвола ваш проект (гуглится как) 4)  Точно не помню, СкримМсг выводит на экран (если разрешено), а лог в консоль отладчика (студии)

Comment: (1) достаточно! Видимо, надо разбираться с нодами на картинке. Вы ничего подозрительного не видите? PrintString отрабатывает (сообщение появляется). Может, нельзя параллельно посылать на мой метод?

Comment: Разобрался с нодами. Теперь отлаживаю. Почему падает при попытке входа в конструктор ARamaUDPSender? Исключение выдаёт анриал. Пытался создать не на стеке, а в куче, так сразу ругается на new.

Comment: это я уже хз, попробуйте на форуме анрила спросить

Comment: Разобрался! Сейчас приведу код, может кому то пригодится.Так и знал, что с анриалом на этом форуме не ахти.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void ACameraPawn::OnBoneHit(FString bone)
{
    if (bone == "none") return;
    UWorld* World = GetWorld();

    ARamaUDPSender* pSender;
    for (TActorIterator<ARamaUDPSender> It(World); It; ++It)
    {
        pSender = *It;
        pSender->StartUDPSender("UdpSendSocket", "127.0.0.1", 11111);
        pSender->RamaUDPSender_SendString(bone);
        break;
    }
}
```